# Is there a way to make a short cut icon that executes a sh file in android?

Tags: apk, home-screen-shortcuts, termux, app-icons

I made a sh file for being executed in termux, i want to make an icon that opens termux and execute that sh file. Kind an apk icon, that when you mash it executes the program

Comment: See this discussion for possible ways: https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/1730

Comment: [Termux Widget](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Widget)

Comment: Use the termux widget add-on is not viable, because my program is interactive.

Comment: Using Termux Widget you can create an icon in home/launcher app. Tapping that would execute the command you specified while creating the widget icon. What else are you asking for?

Answer (score 1):

Use the termux::tasker plugin in tasker or use the native termux task from the tasker function.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idea. Would you mind to add details for those not familiar with the two mentioned options? What would one need to do to achieve the goal with them?